# Change made URL to own URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change the search URL my website makes after a search in my search box. The URL it now shows is: `search.php?name=i&submit=`

I was looking on an .htaccess page and made this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /search.php?name=i&submit= /?s=i
```

But the URL still is the same. Anybody knows how to do this?

The URL data comes out of this:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
   $string = $_GET['name'];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_name WHERE first_name LIKE '%{$string}%'";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your database query is very dangerous. Please read about SQL injection!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, my site is not visible to the public people. Still learning, so I will read about it.

Comment: @D.Ester have you restarted(reloaded) apache(httpd) service after each option's  change?

Comment: I have tried to restart XAMPP, but with no result. This was a local test, normally I work on a hosted domain.

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture your `GET` parameters explicitly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([0-9a-z]+)&(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?s=%1 [R=301,L]
```